# IndexError, but more likely I/O error

Tags: python-2.7

Unsure of why I am getting this error.  I'm reading from a file called columns_unsorted.txt, then trying to write to columns_unsorted.txt.  There error is on fan_on = string_j[1], saying list index out of range. Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fileinput
import collections

# open document to record results into
j = open('./columns_unsorted.txt', 'r')
# note this is a file of rows of space-delimited date in the format <1384055277275353 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 22:47:57> on each row, the first term being unix times, the last human time, the middle binary indicating which machine event happened

# open document to read from
l = open('./columns_sorted.txt', 'w')

# CREATE ARRAY CALLED EVENTS
events = collections.deque()
i = 1

# FILL ARRAY WITH "FACTS" ROWS; SPLIT INTO FIELDS, CHANGE TYPES AS APPROPRIATE
for line in j:      # columns_unsorted
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    string_j = line.split(' ')
    time = str(string_j[0])
    fan_on = int(string_j[1])
    fan_off = int(string_j[2])    
    heater_on = int(string_j[3])
    heater_off = int(string_j[4])
    space_on = int(string_j[5])
    space_off = int(string_j[6])
    pump_on = int(string_j[7])
    pump_off = int(string_j[8])
    event_time = str(string_j[9])

    row = time, fan_on, fan_off, heater_on, heater_off, space_on, space_off, pump_on, pump_off, event_time
    events.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `readlines` function, no?

You have to do:

```
 j = open('./columns_unsorted.txt', 'r')
 l = j.readlines()
 for line in l:
     # what you want to do with each line
```

---

In the future, you should print some of your variables, just to be sure the code is working as you want it to, and to help you identifying problems.
(for example, if in your code you would `print string_j` you would see what kind of problem you have)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was an inconsistent line in the data file.  Forgive my haste in posting